# Golang stretchr testify mock calls to a function within same class

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I am pretty new to Golang and writing unit test for a function (I am using stretchr testify for mocks). This function however calls another function in same class. But when unit testing the first function, I want to mock the call to second function because I do not want it to call the second function in real. This was easy in Java, but I am not finding any useful information for this in Go. Here is some code snippet for my functions:

```
func (p *Prod) GetProducts(name string, request *prod.ProductRequest) (detail *prod.Department, err error) {
    ....
    ....
    if err = p.getDetails(ctx, detail.Id); err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
        return
    }
    
    ...
    ...
}

func (p *Prod) GetDetails(name string, Id string) error {
    ....
    ....
}
```

As you can see here, `GetProducts` is the function that I am trying to unit test and this function calls `GetDetails`. I would like to mock the call to `GetDetails`. Is this possible in Go? Do we typically mock such function calls in Go. Is it recommended? If yes, whats the right way to do it?

In my test, I have:

```
for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
    p := &Prod{
        ...
        ds:     tt.fields.ds,

    }
    p.GetProducts("somestring", request)
    })
}
```

This calls the function GetProducts. But now I don't know what changes to make so the call to GetDetails can be mocked. I would appreciate any help on this

Comment: I don't think is possible. Check this Github issue https://github.com/stretchr/testify/issues/29. The solution would be to separate concerns if possible

Comment: @PabloFlores What exactly do you mean by "The solution would be to separate concerns if possible"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Depending on the responsibilities of your struct, it may be worth adding a new interface (ProdDetailer or something like that) whose responsibility is fetching Details. This way you can pass the interface as a parameter to GetProducts or add it as another field inside your Prod struct. Interfaces are really easy to mock in golang

Comment: You can even embed the ProdDetailer interface to your Prod struct in order to avoid dramatic changes in your API design